# Capturing rest of returned values from function into list

Tags: lua

Given simple function:

```lua
function pullEvent()
  return "eventName", "eventArg1", "eventArg2", "eventArg3", "eventArg4"
end
```

where number of returned values depends on first returned value, how can I capture first returned value into one variable and all remaining into list?

I can imagine something like:

```lua
local eventName, { eventArgs } = pullEvent()
```

but that is invalid syntax.

Way I'm doing it now is:

```lua
local event = { pullEvent() }
local eventName, eventArgs = event[1], { table.unpack(event, 2) }
```

which works, but I'd like to ask, if there is shorter way of doing it. Preferably without creating `event` variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, you need to use functions and/or `select` to deal with varargs. In your case:

```lua
local function nameAndArgs(head, ...)
    return head, {...}
end
```

which you can then use as

```lua
-- eventArgs will be a table
local eventName, eventArgs = nameAndArgs(pullEvent())
```

this simple solution assumes that the event args are never `nil`, otherwise you potentially get a table with holes where trailing `nil`s are stripped; the vararg `1, nil, 2, nil` would become the table `{[1] = 1, [3] = 2}` - in newer Lua versions you could use `table.pack` to have Lua store the count of the vararg (`select("#", ...)`) in the `n` field of the table, allowing exactly restoring it to a vararg using `table.unpack(t, 1, t.n)`.

However, you most likely don't want to pack tables. All you want is a "switch" based on the event name which assigns the arguments to variables. This might look as follows:

```lua
local function handleEvent(eventName, ...)
    if eventName == "foo" then
        local bar = ...
        -- do something
    elseif eventName == "bar" then
        local foobar, quux = ...
        -- do something
    else
        error"unknown event"
    end
end
handleEvent(pullEvent())
```

or, more elegantly (and potentially more efficiently if you have many handlers, since it leverages an O(1) hash table lookup rather than doing O(n) comparisons on average), using the "dispatch table of functions" pattern:

```lua
local eventHandlers = {
    foo = function(bar)
        -- do something
    end,
    bar = function(foobar, quux)
        -- do something
    end,
}
local function handleEvent(eventName, ...)
    return assert(eventHandlers[eventName], "unknown event")(...)
end
handleEvent(pullEvent())
```

Comment: Ok, so there isn't any special syntax for this. Something like js object destructuring. But this works great.
At least got something to hope for in next lua releases.

Comment: @PatrikCapaySK well, in contrast to JS, Lua aims to be pretty minimalist. There is only a little bit of syntactic sugar; stuff like `continue` or `?.` is missing just as well. Often you can write yourself helpful utility functions however; for example I have a `nilget(t, "x", "y", "z")` which is equivalent to `t?.x?.y?.z`. The other option is to write yourself (or to just use) a preprocessor to add all the syntactic sugar you want :)